# Retrofit with Halarious and Teleport.org

Tags: java, android, json, api

I'm working on a small android app that uses the teleport.org API to list the urban areas. To do so, I'm using the following response URL:

https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/

The response looks like this:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "curies": [
      {
        "href": "https://developers.teleport.org/api/resources/Location/#!/relations/{rel}/",
        "name": "location",
        "templated": true
      }
    ],
    "self": {
      "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/"
    },
    "ua:item": [
      {
        "href": "https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/teleport:u173z/",
        "name": "Amsterdam"
      }
    ]
  },
  "count": 153
}
```

What this gives me is a json file in HAL format. Since I'm using retrofit to load my API I need a custom converter to get this info stored in the POJO classes. I picked Halarious for this. http://halarious.ch/

I've set it up like this.

MainActivity:

```
String url = "https://api.teleport.org/api/";
TextView txt_city;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    txt_city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_city);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    getCities();

}

void getCities() {
    //Creating Rest Services
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(HALConverterFactory.create(CityData.class))
            .build();

    RestInterface service = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);

    Call<CityData> call = service.getCityList();


    call.enqueue(new Callback<CityData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CityData> call, Response<CityData> response) {
            try {
                String city = response.body().getUaItem().get(0).getName();
                //Log.e("stad", city);

                txt_city.setText("city 12  :  " + city);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CityData> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
        }
    });
}
```

HALConverterFactory.class:

```
public final class HALConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    private final Gson gson;

    public static HALConverterFactory create(Class<?> type) {
        return new HALConverterFactory(type);
    }

    private HALConverterFactory(Class<?> type) {
        if (!HalResource.class.isAssignableFrom(type))
            throw new NullPointerException("Type should be a subclass of HalResource");
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(HalResource.class, new HalSerializer());
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(HalResource.class, new HalDeserializer(type));
        builder.setExclusionStrategies(new HalExclusionStrategy());
        this.gson = builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new HALResponseBodyConverter<>(gson);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return super.requestBodyConverter(type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations, retrofit);
    }
}
```

HALResponseBodyConverter.class:

```
final class HALResponseBodyConverter<T extends HalResource> implements Converter<ResponseBody, T>{

    private final Gson gson;

    HALResponseBodyConverter(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
    }

    @Override public T convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
        BufferedSource source = value.source();
        try {
            String s = source.readString(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            return (T) gson.fromJson(s, HalResource.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            closeQuietly(source);
        }
    }

    private static void closeQuietly(Closeable closeable) {
        if (closeable == null) return;
        try {
            closeable.close();
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm having the following POJO classes.

CityData:

```
public class CityData implements HalResource {

    @HalLink
    private List<Cury> curies = new ArrayList<Cury>();
    private Self self;
    private List<UaItem> uaItem = new ArrayList<UaItem>();
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    private Integer count;

    //getters and setters
}
```

UaItem:

```
public class UaItem implements HalResource {
    @HalLink
    private String href;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    //getters and setters
}
```

What I wanna do now is retrieving the following:

```
String city = response.body().getUaItem().get(0).getName();
```

But the problem is that my getUaItem is completely empty. It just returns []. So get(0) is useless since the array is empty. I can get the count tho, since that's on a top level, but the UaItem is causing me problems. Why is this?

Kind regards,

Wouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is caused by the fact that the original response variable name is `ua:Item`, not `uaItem`. Probably the automatic mapping isn't working here. You could fix it by explicitly writing out the variable name:

```
@serializedName("ua:item") private List<UaItem> uaItem = new ArrayList<UaItem>();
```

Comment: I'm not on this project anymore so I'm not in the position to check this. We ended up using a different API without HAL notation. So just leaving this here for someone that is running into the same problem as me to try it out. Will approve it for now, until someone states otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't work. You need to use `@HalLink(name = "ua:item")`. Look at below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `@HalLink` on each link. You forgot to add it on `CityData.self`

If you have to specify another name, just use the `name` attribute.

```
@HalLink(name = "ua:item")
private List<UaItem> uaItem = new ArrayList<UaItem>();
```